# Write HTML table to existing MS Word document using Replace and coldfusion cfsavecontent

Tags: replace, coldfusion, ms-word, html-table

I'm using the replace function to replace data using a placeholder in a word document.  I'm trying to do the same with a table.  I can output my page that has tables to MS Word but when I use cfsavecontent and try to do a replace into an existing document, it doesn't work.

Code:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="rosterTb">
<table border='2' style='width:75%'>  
    <thead>
        <caption><cfoutput><cfif Dept NEQ "">#Dept#:</cfif> Sales Roster</cfoutput><caption>
        <tr>
            <cfloop list='#ArrayToList(qGetEmpData.getColumnNames())#' index='col' >
                <cfif col NEQ "ID">
                    <cfset col = ReplaceNoCase(#col#,"_", " ","all")>
                    <th><cfoutput>#col#</cfoutput></th>
                </cfif>
             </cfloop>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <cfloop query = "qGetTableFldList">
        <cfset total = total + #qGetTableFldList.Total#>
        <tr>
            <cfloop list='#ArrayToList(qGetEmpData.getColumnNames())#' index='col' >
                <cfif col NEQ "ID">
                <td>
                    <cfif IsNumeric(qGetEmpData[col][currentrow])>
                         <center>
                             <cfoutput>#qGetEmpData[col][currentrow]#</cfoutput>
                         </center>
                    <cfelse>
                             <cfoutput>#qGetEmpData[col][currentrow]#</cfoutput>
                    </cfif>
                </td>
                </cfif>
            </cfloop>
        </tr>
        </cfloop>
        <cfset x = 1>
        <cfset trtdcolspan = "<tr><td><b>Total Count:</b></td><td colspan = #x#>">
        <center>
            <cfoutput>#trtdcolspan#Total#</td></tr></cfoutput></center>
    </tbody>
</table>
</cfsavecontent> 
<cfset rtf = Replace(rtf,'%rTable%','#rosterTb#',"one") />
```

%rTable%  is the place holder in the document where I want the table to be placed.

This is the result in the word document:

```
<table border='2' style='width:75%'>
    <thead>
        <caption>Sales: Roster</caption>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
            </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Richard</td> 
            <td>Smith</td>
        </tr>
        <center>
        <tr> 
            <td><b>Total Count:</b></td>
            <td colspan = 1>6</td>
        </tr>
        </center>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I've also tried setting the table to a variable but it doesn't seem to like the looping or the index for the column names.

```
<tableborder='2'style='width:75%'>
     <thead>
          <caption>
             <cfoutput><cfif  Dept NEQ  ''>Dept:</cfif>Roster</cfoutput>
          </caption>
          <tr>
             <cflooplist='ID,First Name,Last Name 'index='col'>
                 <cfif col NEQ 'ID'>
                     <th>
                         <cfoutput>First Name</cfoutput>
                     </th>
                 </cfif>
             </cfloop> 
          </tr>
     </thead>
  <tbody>
      <cfloopquery='qGetTableFldList'>
      <cfset total=total+6>
          <tr>
              <cflooplist='ID,FirstName,LastName 'index='col'>
                  <cfif col NEQ 'ID'>
                      <td>
                          <cfif  IsNumeric(qEmpData[col][currentrow])>
                              <center>qEmpData[col][currentrow]</center>
                          <cfelse>
                              qEmpData[col][currentrow]
                          </cfif>
                      </td>
                  </cfif>
              </cfloop>
          </tr>
      </cfloop>
      <cfset x=1>
          <center>
              <cfoutput>
                  <tr>
                       <td><b>Total Count:</b></td><tdcolspan=15>0</td>
                  </tr>
              </cfoutput>
          </center>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'd greatly appreciate any assistance.

Comment: I can think to two ways to do this. Neither are easy:
1. Interact with POI directly: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi_word/apache_poi_word_tables.htm
2. Read the XML data out of the word document and insert the XML needed for the table.

Comment: Using that tutorial looks more involved than what I need to tackle.  I guess I shouldn't spend a lot of time on something that already works.  Thank you so much for the response.